# Database open/close - database not open

Tags: android, database

In every Activity, I have added in the `onCreate()` Method the following lines:

```
database = new DatabaseHelper(this);  
database.open();
```

And in every `onDestroy()` Method the following line:

```
database.close();
```

So as long as the activity is not destroyed the database is opened.

Sometimes some users get a force close if my app wants to update something in the database.

```
Following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1776)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1731)
```

How can this happen?
If I open the database in `onCreate()` and close it in `onDestroy()` Should it be always opened?!

Comment: what if activity A calls its `onDestroy` while the user is in activity B, and tries to use the database? just close your database when you're done with it.

Comment: I open the database in every activity!  So activity A has its own open and activity B. If B closes his connection, database connection on A should be still opened.

Comment: that's not correct, look at my answer update.

Comment: Thanks again! I understand. So i should close and open the database after every update/write/read to the database? I think its better to close it only ones. But when should i do this if i have more than one activity?

Answer (score 3):

Binnyb is right, most likely your database is closed in background activity `onDestroy` while the error raises in the active activity. You have to open/close database just at the time you need to save/retrieve the data.

UPD:

Look at the [google's dev docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29), getWritableDatabase returns a cached object if a db was opened already.

Comment: Thanks, but if every activity has its own open and close, there should not be a problem! Activity A opens the database, and activity B also. So 2 connections are open.

Comment: What has make you think so? Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase() .. open database returns you a cached database object if it was opened already.

Comment: OK this was my fault. I understand now the problem. But on which activity should i close the database if i have more than one activity? I want to close the db only if all my activities are destroyed for better performance...

Comment: @chrisonline Do you really see any performance issues with closing db just after you're done with it?

Comment: Yes i think its not performant.
For example: User opens the activity -> open database -> read -> close database! User hits the change button on one entry -> open database - close database afterwards he hits the next entry -> open database - close database!

I think better is to open it ones and make a close only if all activities are destroyed... But i dont have a trigger to see that this is the last activity who is destroyed..

Comment: @chrisonline Well, I can understand that you think it is not performant. But do you really any slowdowns doing that? In other words, can you actually prove that? If no, then what you're doing is premature optimization.

Comment: :-) You're right i can't prove that! But i can prove that you have more source code lines, because you have to add on every database function a open and close ;-) And on every tutorial, also on Android Developers, ther are 1 open in onCreate and 1 close on onDestroy! But i dont find any example with more than one activity.

Comment: @chrisonline well, then I'd try to move the open/close code into ApplicationContext.